# Wrong button color mahapss metro

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm just use this code

```
<Button Content="hi" 
        Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="223" Margin="0,316,0,0" Height="39"/>
```

in xaml:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Launcher.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="Launcher" 
        Height="455.745" 
        Width="690.319"
        ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
```

but this button in the wrong color when i click on it

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7zYc.jpg]

Comment: can't see any button in your code. Please post relevant codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in MahApps.Metro and was fixed with commit [3f82d22](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/commit/3f82d2242ab81c87997063d33a63b18cb24db055).